# How do I compare multiple rows and get the min of date in a new column?

Tags: sqlcompare

```
COMPANY PROD    ID  DATE            NAME        REQD_DATE
XYZ 12345   AAA111  7/1/2011    PETER   
XYZ 12345   PPP222  7/1/2002    JOHN    
MNS 67890   ZZZ999  9/1/2005    STEVE   
MNS 67890   DDD555  9/1/2012    MARTIN
```

With reference to this above table say '#temp', 
Whenever COMPANY AND PROD are same, I want to get the min of date {min(DATE)} into column 'REQD_DATE'

Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'd use a group-by on the company+prod fields, and min() on the reqd_date. But you'll have to figure that out on your own. We're not here to do your job for you - you have to show you at least tried this on your own.

Comment: I have tried it in many ways but failed! 

1) I tried using where clause.. 
WHERE a.DATE IN (SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM #temp WHERE DATE = a.DATE)

2) I also tried using an update statement 
update #temp set DATE = 
 case when DATE < (select top 1 min(DATE) from #temp) 
  then DATE
  else '' 
  end

None of these worked! 
Let me try with your method! 
Thanks though!